# Call method without parameters

Tags: c#, list, function, methods, parameters

I have a quick C# question.

I have a list that I need to pass onto a method. So I did this:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(JogadoresList);
f2.novoJogo(JogadoresList);
```

And on another class:

```
public void novoJogo(List<Jogadores> JogadoresList)
    {}
```

But now I want to call the *novoJogo* method from a

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

method. How can I call the *novoJogo* method if I don't have parameters to pass onto it and don't want to replace the novoJogo's list? Thank you.

Comment: Note that you **can't** "replace" novoJogo's list. That reference died when the function last returned.

Comment: What is happening in method novoJogo. Is there any meaning calling the method without List<Jogadores>

Comment: @BradleyDotNET So say I wanted to create a new list and store there the exact same list that is passed as a parameter in _novoJogo_ . How could I do that?

Comment: You really should consider asking new question about what you actually trying to do as you already have good answers to question you've *asked*. Maybe new question should be "pass copy of list so method does not change original"?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `novoJogo` passing `null` value  as parameter:

```
novoJogo(null);
```

Or an empty list:

```
novoJogo(new List<Jogadores>());
```

Also in the `novoJogo` method, you could define the `List<>` as an [optional parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

```
public void novoJogo(List<Jogadores> JogadoresList=null)
{}
```

Then, you can call it without passing the argument in the the click event as I show below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   novoJogo();
}
```

Comment: and that would mean it would delete the list I passed to it earlier, right? That can't happen...

Comment: @MiguelPT That would be highly dependent on what `novoJogo` actually *does* with the list.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET it reads and modifies it's values, that's why I did not want to replace them.

Answer (score 1):

Either the method needs the list, or it doesn't. So the fact you are asking this is... troubling.

However, you have a couple options. Just pass `null`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Hopefully you held onto that reference!
   f2.novoJogo(null);
}
```

Or use default arguments/optional parameters:

```
public void novoJogo(List<Jogadores> JogadoresList = null)
{}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Hopefully you held onto that reference!
   f2.novoJogo();
}
```

In both cases, make sure that `novoJogo` will be OK with a null list passed to it (NRE is really easy to get here if you weren't careful). And consider if your design makes sense here, if only part of the function needs the list, should that really have been two functions instead of one?

Comment: I need it to have the list...but I don't know how to pass it as a parameter since button1.click does not receive parameters...

Comment: @MiguelPT Is the list stored off somewhere you can access it? Say as a class member?

Comment: Yes, sure. But the changes made in _novoJogo_ are not being saved although I could easily do that...

Comment: @MiguelPT Sounds like you need to reconsider your design. That whole thing seems very off.

Answer (score 0):

Change the access-level of **JogadoresList** to `public static` or `internal static` so you can access it via `button1_click`.